# ERROR TypeError: can't access property "salt", ciphertext is null

Tags: angular, typescript, cryptography, cryptojs

I am struggling with encriptation of the localStorage, I am using typescript with VisualStudio Code.

Here is the error

ERROR TypeError: can't access property "salt", ciphertext is null

[image]

Here is my code

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class StorageService {
  constructor() {}

  // If the logged in user details are stored in local storage the user will stay logged in if they refresh
  // the browser and also between browser sessions until they logout

  // Para cambiar el tipo de storage a utilizar modificar el valor en el archivo de enviorment correspondiente
  // los valores posibles son LOCALSTORAGE o SESSIONSTORAGE

  //Llave publica de prueba
  default_llave: string  = "prueba";

  //Funcion de encriptado
  encriptar(
    texto: string,
    llave = this.default_llave
  ) {
    var textoEncriptado = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(texto, llave).toString()
    console.log(textoEncriptado);

    return textoEncriptado;
  }

  desencriptar(
    textoEncriptado : string,
    llave = this.default_llave
  ) {
    var textoDesencriptado =
      CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(textoEncriptado, llave)
    .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    console.log("El texto desencriptado es " + textoDesencriptado);
    return textoDesencriptado;
  }





  setItem(key: string, value: string): void {
    if (environment.storage === "SESSIONSTORAGE") {
      sessionStorage.setItem(key, this.encriptar(value, this.default_llave));
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(key, this.encriptar(value,this.default_llave));
    }
  }

  getItem(key: string): string {
    if (environment.storage === "SESSIONSTORAGE") {
      return this.desencriptar(sessionStorage.getItem(key),this.default_llave);
    }
    else {
      return this.desencriptar(localStorage.getItem(key),this.default_llave);
    }
  }




  key(index: number): string {
    if (environment.storage === "SESSIONSTORAGE") {
      return sessionStorage.key(index);
    } else {
      return localStorage.key(index);
    }
  }

  removeItem(key: string): void {
    if (environment.storage === "SESSIONSTORAGE") {
      sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with this try - catch stament

```js
getItem(key: string): string {
    if (environment.storage === "SESSIONSTORAGE") {
      try {
        return this.desencriptar(sessionStorage.getItem(key), this.default_llave);
      }
      catch (e) {
        return null;
      }
    }
    else {
      try {
      return this.desencriptar(localStorage.getItem(key),this.default_llave);
      }
      catch (e) {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
```